# Please can someone solve this ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The equation is similar to the generalised bass model

$y'(t) = g(t)\left(p + \frac{q}{n} y(t)\right) \left(n - y(t)\right) $

where the initial conditions g(0) = 0, y(0) = 1, the constant c = 1.

This is part of a market penetration model I am working one. Please show workings as I am not really good with ODE.

Thank you

Comment: Shall we assume $p,q,n$ are all constants? I also think you will need to give more information on $g(t)$ if you want a concrete answer.

Comment: @Amzoti The parameters are all constants and I know their values, the function g(t) is a variable and the cost with respect to time. g(t) is a linear function

Answer (score 0):

First a substitutions $q/n=a$

$\frac{y'(t)}{(p+ay)(n-y)}=g(t)$

$\int\frac{dy(t)}{(p+ay)(n-y)}=\int g(t) dt$

$\int (\frac{1}{an+p}(\frac{a}{(p+ay)}+\frac {1}{(n-y)})dy=\int g(t)dt $

$ ln(p+ay)-ln(n-y)=(an+p)\int g(t)dt$

$ ln\frac{p+ay}{n-y}+y(0)=(an+p)\int g(t)dt +C $

Maybe this helps... If g(t) is a linear function then there would be no problems in integrating...

$ln\frac{p+ay}{n-y}=(an+p)\int g(t)dt +C-y(0)$

$\frac{p+ay}{n-y}=e^{(an+p)\int g(t)dt}$

and now you can easily get y(t)...

$K=e^{(an+p)\int g(t)dt}$

$\frac{p+ay}{n-y}=K$

$p+ay=Kn-Ky$

$y(a+K)=Kn-p$

$y=\frac{n e^{(an+p)\int g(t) dt}-p}{a+ e^{(an+p)\int g(t)dt} }$

Comment: Thank you @Markisa. Can I just integrate g(t) out the equation and add it to the solution of the ordinary differential equation?

Comment: Yes this can be done as usual, nothing special to add :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a separable equation hence the usual methods apply. To wit, $y$ solves this if and only if
$$
\frac{ny'(t)}{(np + q y(t))(n - y(t))}=g(t).
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{n(q+p)}{(np + q y(t))(n - y(t))}=\frac{q}{np + q y(t)}+\frac1{n - y(t)},
$$
hence
$$
\frac{np+qy(t)}{n-y(t)}=c\,\mathrm e^{(q+p)G(t)},
$$
for some constant $c$, where
$$
G(t)=\int_0^tg(s)\mathrm ds.
$$
that is,
$$
y(t)=n\,\frac{c\,\mathrm e^{(q+p)G(t)}-p}{c\,\mathrm e^{(q+p)G(t)}+q}.
$$
If $y(0)=1$, then
$$
c=\frac{np+q}{n-1},
$$
hence
$$
y(t)=n\,\frac{(np+q)\,\mathrm e^{(q+p)G(t)}-(n-1)p}{(np+q)\,\mathrm e^{(q+p)G(t)}+(n-1)q}.
$$

Comment: Thank  you @Did. Does this mean my $t$ has to be broken down into different segments again?

Comment: I do not understand "t has to be broken down into different segments again".

Comment: Let me rephrase that, can I just integrate $G(t)$ separately and substitute it into my $y(t)$ equation? Thank you

Comment: Well, this is what the last identity says, no? Identify $G$, plug it in the RHS, and you get $y$.